# Why there is no alpha parameter for GaussianNB()?

Tags: scikit-learn, naive-bayes-classifier

Why there is no alpha argument ( smoothing parameter in Laplace smoothing) for GaussianNB() in sklearn library? ? Although BernoulliNB() and MultinomialNB() have an alpha parameter but GaussianNB() doesn't have ?

Answer (score 0):

Because smoothing makes sense only for `BernoulliNB` and `MultinomialNB`, which have categorical features, whereas `GaussianNB` works with numerical features which are supposed to follow a normal distribution.

For `BernoulliNB` and `MultinomialNB`, the features often represent frequencies and can be zero. In theory, this can cause one or several of the conditional probabilities to be zero, and therefore occasionally make the posterior probability zero. It can even cause the posterior to be zero for all the classes, an inconsistency. Smoothing prevents these issues.

In `GaussianNB` the conditional probability is calculated from the normal distribution so they can never be zero, thus this problem cannot happen.

Comment: What confuses me is that the probability that a continuous random variable equals some value is always zero , like here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/why-is-the-probability-zero-for-any-given-value-of-a-normal-distribution

Comment: @AAA As far as I remember this is usually handled by taking the probability of the interval around the value instead, i.e. instead of calculating $p(x)$ one calculates $p(x \in [x-\epsilon/2, x+\epsilon/2])$ with $\epsilon$ a fixed constant, e.g. 0.000001. This would be specific to GaussianNB of course.